# scipy sparse matrices, copy argument

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

What is the function of **copy** argument in construction of scipy sparse arrays?

```
scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(arg1, shape=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
```

It doesn't seem to do anything!

When I construct a sparse matrix from another one and explicitly set  copy=False, changing one matrix does not change the other.

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np
A = sp.csc_matrix(np.array([[1,0],[0,0]]))
B = sp.csr_matrix(A, copy=False)
B[1,1] = 1 #editing B should change A but it does not 
print A.data, B.data #these values are different
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both CSC and CSR matrices are internally represented as three 1D arrays. These three arrays will in general be different for different formats, even if they represent the exact same data. There is therefore no way that you can have to sparse matrix objects pointing to the same data but accessing it in different formats.

What the `copy` argument can allow you to do is having two sparse matrix objects of the same format pointing to the same data. For example:

```
a = sps.csr_matrix([[1, 0], [0, 0]])
b = sps.csr_matrix(a, copy=False)

>>> a.data
array([1])
>>> b.data
array([1])
>>> a[0, 0] = 2
>>> a.data
array([2])
>>> b.data
array([2])
```

This also has limitations, for instance for the CSR (and CSC) format(s), breaking the sparsity structure will break the commonality of data, as it requires instantiating new arrays, not simply changing the values in the existing ones:

```
>>> a[1, 1] = 5
>>> a.data
array([2, 5])
>>> b.data
array([2])
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how `del` works, but the following implies to me that data is copied even `copy=False` is specified:
`print S.todense();`
`S2 = sp.sparse.csr_matrix(S,copy=False);`
`del S.data,S.indices,S.indptr,S;`
`print S2.todense() # <-- Identical to first print;`

Comment: Python keeps a reference count for every object. When you e.g. `del S.data` the corresponding array has its reference count reduced by one, and the `.data` attribute is removed from the object. If no other object points to this same array, then the reference count drops down to zero and it gets garbage collected. But if other objects point to it, the array will not be garbage collected, and even though it is no longer accessible from `S` because you got rid of the attribute, it is kept around for `S2` to use.